# Не работает запрос для нескольких сущностей SQL

Tags: sql

Мне нужно, чтобы для каждого пути в составе выводилось кол-во свободных мест. Расчет идёт так: Находим нужный нам путь по way, id_way подходящего пути пути, по id_way_a находим id_connection в connections, по id_connection находим покупку билета в civil_bookings через id_connection_a и считаем их. Вопрос состоит в том, что для одного подходящего пути мой запрос работает корректно. А если под название подходит несколько путей то оно считает сумму свободных мест каждого из подходящих путей. Как сделать так, чтобы при совпадении нескольких путей считало для каждого отдельно а не для всех сразу?
[image: ER-диаграмма с таблицами]

```sql
SELECT (20*(SELECT COUNT(id_carriage_a) FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a = 6))) AS 'all_places')
 - 
(SELECT COUNT(id_civil_booking) AS 'block_places' FROM civil_bookings WHERE (id_connection_a IN(SELECT id_connection FROM connections WHERE id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE (way LIKE '%' + @way + '%')))))) AS 'amount_place'
```

Как я понял, по логике построенного мною запроса, он считает для двух сразу так как я указал `id_way_a IN(...)` и он находит id_way 2+ подходящих и отсюда высчитывается сумма. Как заставить его видеть все найденные пути как разные, в которых считать всё надо отдельно?

Полный запрос выглядит так:

```sql
SELECT id_way, time_out, way, (
(SELECT (54*(SELECT COUNT(id_carriage_a) FROM connections WHERE (id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a = 7))
+2*(SELECT COUNT(id_carriage_a) FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a = 1))
+36*(SELECT COUNT(id_carriage_a) FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a = 4))
+20*(SELECT COUNT(id_carriage_a) FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a = 6))) AS 'all_places')
 - 
(SELECT COUNT(id_civil_booking) AS 'block_places' FROM civil_bookings WHERE (id_connection_a IN(SELECT id_connection FROM connections WHERE 
id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE (way LIKE '%' + @way + '%')))))) AS 'amount_place' 

FROM ways WHERE 
( id_way IN (SELECT id_way_a FROM connections WHERE (
SELECT COUNT(id_civil_booking) AS 'block_places' FROM civil_bookings WHERE (
id_connection_a IN(
SELECT id_connection FROM connections WHERE id_way_a IN(
SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE (way LIKE '%' + @way + '%'))))) < 
(SELECT 
(54*(SELECT COUNT(id_carriage_a) FROM connections WHERE (
id_way_a IN(
SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a = 7))
+2*(SELECT COUNT(id_carriage_a) FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (
id_way_a IN(
SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a = 1))
+36*(SELECT COUNT(id_carriage_a) FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (
id_way_a IN(
SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a = 4))
+20*(SELECT COUNT(id_carriage_a) FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (
id_way_a IN(
SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a = 6))) AS 'all_places'))

AND id_way IN(
SELECT DISTINCT id_way_a FROM connections WHERE (
id_way_a IN(
SELECT id_way FROM ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%')))
)
```

Comment: Практически ничего не ясно, что требуется и что есть. Но если нужно считать для разных id_way, значит надо все данные сгруппировать по этому полю, а дальше избавляться от IN и менять это на join подзапросов, получающих данные из разных таблиц по id_way. За основу по connections можно взять что то вроде https://pastebin.com/L5aCiGVF посмотрите на выдаваемый результат и решите как к этому лучше выполнять join количеств из civil_bookings

Comment: Спасибо за конструкцию CASE id_... WHEN ... THEN ... END. Не знал, что её можно использовать таким образом. Это значительно упрощает запрос.

Comment: Хотя ту циферку 2, 20, 36, ... я бы вообще вынес в БД (там же для id_carriage_a есть небось табличка, где они храняться) и тогда сделал бы join с ней и выкинул в том числе и этот безумный case. что бы не править потом код, если вдруг новый carriage появится

Comment: Может что то в этом роде https://pastebin.com/fkmcPCZ6 берем из connections значения с плюсом для каждого id_way, объединяем с количествами с минусами из bookings и потом считаем общую сумму, пролучим как раз разности в разрезе путей. а потом уже этот запрос можно еще одном select обернуть и делать с полученным то что требуется

Comment: Проблему почти полностью решил LEFT JOIN, спасибо вам огромное. Чуть позже в ответе вопроса выложу полный запрос. Еще раз спасибо. Как тут +rep поставить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще раз огромное спасибо Mike за подсказку с INNER JOIN и CASE. Решилось всё тем, что я сделал так:

```sql
SELECT id_way, time_out, way, c.d
FROM Train_Station.dbo.ways 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id_way as 'w', b.am-a.am as 'd'
FROM
(SELECT id_way, COUNT(id_civil_booking) AS 'am' FROM
Train_Station.dbo.civil_bookings 
 LEFT JOIN
Train_Station.dbo.connections ON id_connection_a=id_connection 
 LEFT JOIN
Train_Station.dbo.ways ON connections.id_way_a=ways.id_way
 WHERE (way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') group by id_way)a 
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT id_way_a, SUM( CASE id_carriage_a
            WHEN 1 THEN 36
            WHEN 4 THEN 36
            WHEN 6 THEN 20
            WHEN 7 THEN 54
            END
          )AS am
  FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM Train_Station.dbo.ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a IN(1,4,6,7)
 ) GROUP BY id_way_a) b
 ON a.id_way=b.id_way_a)c
 ON c.w=ways.id_way

 WHERE ( id_way IN
(SELECT id_way FROM
 (SELECT id_way as 'w', b.am-a.am as 'd'
FROM
(SELECT id_way, COUNT(id_civil_booking) AS 'am' FROM
Train_Station.dbo.civil_bookings 
 LEFT JOIN
Train_Station.dbo.connections ON id_connection_a=id_connection 
 LEFT JOIN
Train_Station.dbo.ways ON connections.id_way_a=ways.id_way
 WHERE (way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') group by id_way)a 
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT id_way_a, SUM( CASE id_carriage_a
            WHEN 1 THEN 36
            WHEN 4 THEN 36
            WHEN 6 THEN 20
            WHEN 7 THEN 54
            END
          )AS am
  FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM Train_Station.dbo.ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') AND id_carriage_a IN(1,4,6,7)
 ) GROUP BY id_way_a) b
 ON a.id_way=b.id_way_a) g
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT id_way, (0) as 'zero' FROM Train_Station.dbo.ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%') j
 ON g.w=j.id_way
 WHERE (g.d>j.zero)
AND id_way IN(SELECT DISTINCT id_way_a FROM Train_Station.dbo.connections WHERE (id_way_a IN(SELECT id_way FROM Train_Station.dbo.ways WHERE way LIKE '%' + @way + '%')))))
```